# PhpMailer able to send mail from Windows but not CentOS

Tags: apache, centos, phpmailer, php

I have Apache w/ php on my windows for testing purpose. 
I also have Apache w/ php on my production CentOS 6.4 server.

I am able to perfectly send an email on my windows server using PHPMailer.
However, I am not able to send it on my centos server.

This is my code:

```
    require_once('phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');
    $mail = new PHPMailer();  
    $mail->IsSMTP(); 
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;  
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Host = 'mail.example.com';
    $mail->Port = 25; 
    $mail->Username = "mail-daemon@example.com";  
    $mail->Password = "secret";
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';       
    $mail->SetFrom('mail-daemon@example.com', "$name");
    $mail->Subject = "$subj";
    $mail->Body = $body;
    $mail->AddAddress("Support@example.com");
    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        $error = 'Mail error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo; 
        echo "We're sorry, however, an error has occurred. You may manually e-mail us at support@example.com.";
        return false;
    } else {
        echo "Thanks! Your message was successfully sent.";
        return true;
    }
?>
```

Once again, it works perfectly on my Windows Apachhe.
However, the following error occures on CentOS.

```
SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110) <br />The following From address failed: mail-daemon@example.com : Called Mail() without being connected
```

I have tested the firewall and I don't think that's the issue. I even turned it off completely(for testing) and it was still giving me that error.

I have openssl installed and enabled on my php.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I understand from the message is

- that your client can't reach to the mail server or
- the mail server closing connection after a while, before the client sent all of the commands.

If I were you, I would try the followings in order:

1. Ping the mail.example.com to be sure that I can resolve the domain.
2. Telnet to mail.example.com's 25th port to be sure that my server can connect to mail server.
3. Test the mail server by using telnet or another mail client.

You should get stuck at one of those steps and it should help to solve that problem.

Comment: Hello, i just did the test before I was able to read your post.
You were right however, I am not able to telnet at port 25.
I can telnet mail.example.com 465, however, I am not able to telnet mail.example.com 25

I've asked my vps hosting provider and they said they are not blocking anything, perhaps it's the email provider?

I am able to telnet mail.exmaple.com 25 on my other hosts fine.

Comment: You have to connect port 25 to drop an email to the mail server. So that's the problem. Some ISPs blocking port 25 to prevent spam. You can try 587 instead of 25.

Comment: 587 get's refused. 465 works, however, it causes a lot of error on my bb, so need to get that checked.
either way, 26 works instead of 25.
so basically, the solution is use 26/465.
also, since your the only one that tried to help, the best answer goes to you sir.